# How to convert one-hot vector to label index and back in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, one-hot-encoding, multiclass-classification

How to transform vectors of labels to one-hot encoding and back in Pytorch?

The solution to the question was copied to here after having to go through the entire forum discussion, instead of just finding an easy one from googling.

Comment: I don't really see the point of creating a thread to copy-paste a solution from another forum.

Comment: @Ivan https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/347922/913098

Comment: The point is to allow Google searchability. Searching through forums is a waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [the Pytorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytocrh-way-for-one-hot-encoding-multiclass-target-variable/68321)

```
import torch
import numpy as np


labels = torch.randint(0, 10, (10,))

# labels --> one-hot 
one_hot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(labels)
# one-hot --> labels
labels_again = torch.argmax(one_hot, dim=1)

np.testing.assert_equals(labels.numpy(), labels_again.numpy())
```

Comment: Notice [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74784150/913098) for cases where you have to specify the number of classes [which is most of the time]

Answer (score 9):

Since I can't comment on the accepted answer, I just wanted to add that if your target does not include all classes (e.g. because you train in batches), you can specify the number of classes as argument:

```
# labels --> one-hot 
one_hot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target, num_classes=7)
```

Comment: You now have sufficient reputation to comment. I suggest you do this.